# How to open item in new page for more details

Tags: javascript

I want to open item in new page when visitor will click btn with icon search.
I want redirect just item1 to new page and show more details about item1.
I saw same solutions like: window.location='app2.html;
or location.replace('https://...')
Is  better way to do it ?

```
   //app1.html  page1
    <div class="container">
     
       // item 1
         <div class="col-md-3 text-center border border-light m-4">
          <img src="..." alt="..."><br>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="bi bi-search" data-id="1"></i>   // here is btn with id
          </button>
         </div>

       // item2, ...

    </div>


  //app2.html page2  // new page
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a `<a>` component with `href` etc and just let it do his job when clicking on it ?

Comment: I will have 10 items . I want to open specific item in secound page with specific items data.

Comment: You can use a href and pass the query string along with the items and in next page fetch the query string and do you job on the basis of that

Comment: If you replace the window location the effect will be for the tab to be reloaded at the new location so you would have to fetch that data from you API anyway. Or you could pass the data you need in the url query string if possible... But in any case in don't see the interest of implementing an onclick manually just to navigate to a new url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.location.href = "app2.html";` inside an implicit function in js.

```js
 
function test(){
    window.location.href = "http://www.devmedia.com.br";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="test()">Btn</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).